# New to CSS and HTML - Error message reads "special characters must be escaped"

Tags: html

Edited to add: I am creating a button that links to an external URL. I don't want the plain gray default button and have put some style code.

I am able to test this code and it seems to work just fine until I put it in Wordpress where I need it. Then I get an error message that "special characters must be escaped" and that the a tag must be paired. What am I missing here? Thank you!

`<p><a href="URL"rel="noopener noreferrer"target="_blank"><strong><button class="button">Join Group</button></strong></a></p>`

Comment: I don't know why Wordpress would give **that** error, but you have a couple of problems which https://validator.nu/ would pick up.

Comment: a side question, what are you intending to do? a span type button inside of a hyperlink including another button can be considered as bad use..

Comment: `style= button button1` - Not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: look it - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/html-widget-issues-special-character-must-be-escaped/

Answer (score 0):

On your span style you're missing the quotation marks.

```
<p>
    <a href="URL"rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
        <strong>
            <span style="button button1">
                <button class="button button1">Join Group</button>
            </span>
        </strong>
    </a>
</p>
```